# How to write a lightweight executable like uTorrent

Tags: winapi, memory, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programming slim C++ programs (like uTorrent) for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021210/programming-slim-c-programs-like-utorrent-for-windows)

[uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) has always impressed me with its 270KB executable and small memory footprint while competing with similar tools which are 30 times its size. I can think of several other tools on my computer that could use such a "debloated" version.

What methods should one employ in trying to write, let's say, a Twitter client in under 300KB?

- I'm guessing the only language options are C, C++ and Assembler (am I right?).
- Are there frameworks you can still use?
- Do you have to employ those [crazy](http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/) [tactics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942125) from the demo scene to keep the exe small?
- Can something like that still be maintainable?

I am not really a win32 programmer, so parts of this question may not make sense. Corrections are welcome.

Comment: This was recently asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021210/programming-slim-c-programs-like-utorrent-for-windows

Comment: Oops... I was sure I searched enough...

Comment: Huh? I can't close my own question? That's just weird.

Answer (score 0):

my contribution to your opinion:

no crazy tactics in the beginning at least:
 ["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science))

and looking at the first bullet after this:
C, C++ and Assembler: C++, then C, then Assembler.